# WordPress: how do I use a domain name when developing a site on my computer?

Tags: wordpress, dns, mamp

I am working on a wordpress site on my Mac using MAMP.

In Settings > General I have the following:

**WordPress Address (URL)** http://localhost/examplesite

**Site Address** (URL) http://localhost/examplesite

Is it possible to change those addresses to, for instance, http://examplesite.com. This would be for the purpose of SEO testing. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by editing your `/etc/hosts`file. You'll just have to point the localhost's IP address, by default on MAMP : `127.0.0.1` to your custom domain.

Here is a good tutorial about it : 
http://blainsmith.com/articles/quick-and-dirty-local-domain-names-for-mamp